# Bernoulli theorem using quantum and statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, bernoulli-equation

Can someone derive Bernoulli theorem( behavior of fluids) using quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics ( behaviour of atoms and molecules of fluids) ?